# Aggregating tuples into 2D arrays PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm not and expert in SQL and have been looking online for a solution to his problem to no avail.

**Is there a way to aggregate this result:**

[image]

**Into something like this:**

[image]

**With each value in the coordinates array respecting the order of the column `index` from the previous image?**

Thank you.

Comment: Please [do not post a painting of the code and data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use ARRAY_AGG() and sort by another column. Something like this, since I'm too lazy to type the correct table names...

```
SELECT influence_region_id
     , ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY[lat, lng] ORDER BY "index")
FROM your_table -- replace with your table and join
GROUP BY influence_region_id;
```

Ps. Don't use images, impossible to use in most/all SQL editors